# Как в списке имён найти имя файла с наибольшей датой?

Tags: ftp, python-2.7

Имеются файлы с названием типа: "filename_20180325_180109.zip, filename_20180326_020107.zip", т.е. отличаются только числами в конце имени, которыми является дата создания. Важно так же то, что число состоит из двух частей и имеет значение для меня только первая часть, находящаяся до "_". Необходимо скачать только **один** файл с бОльшим числом в конце имени(с последней датой) и положить его рядом со скриптом.

Возможно есть идеи как прикрутить к решению проблемы модуль **fnmatch**

Comment: скачать именно один файл с бОльшим числом в имени

Comment: выходит, что шаг 2

Comment: большее значение у второго файла. т.е. более поздняя дата (2018.03.26)

Comment: да, я Вас понял, такой подход к постановке вопроса более полезен, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если часть с `filename` везде одинаковая, то имена можно просто как строки сравнивать так как формат даты также позволяет сравнения для строк использовать. Поэтому `max()` функция вернёт нужное имя:

```
filenames = ["filename_20180325_180109.zip", "filename_20180326_020107.zip"]
print(max(filenames))
# -> filename_20180326_020107.zip
```

Если первая часть в имени файла может отличаться, тогда можно дату в нужном формате явно изъять из имени для сравнения:

```
import datetime as DT
import re

def most_recent(filename):
    m = re.search(r'_(\d{8})_(\d{6})\.zip$', filename)
    if m:  # matched
        try:
            dt = DT.datetime.strptime(' '.join(m.groups()), '%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            return dt, filename
    return DT.datetime.min, filename
```

Имея ключ для сравнения, легко получить имя с наибольшим временем:

```
print(max(filenames, key=most_recent))
# -> filename_20180326_020107.zip
```

К примеру, что скачать в текущую директорию из заданной ftp директории `dir` самый свежий zip-архив:

```
import fnmatch
import posixpath

def download_most_recent_archive(ftp, dir):
    filename = max(fnmatch.filter(ftp.nlst(dir), '*.zip'), key=most_recent)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + posixpath.join(dir, filename), file.write)
```

Пример:

```
import ftplib

with ftplib.FTP('ftp.example.com', 'user', 'passwd') as ftp:
    download_most_recent_archive(ftp, 'archives')
```